# JQuery .sort() JavaScript Object by property value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sorting

I'm building a game which has a number of NPCs. these NPCs are contained within an array of objects like below:

```
"[
    {
        "name": "Stella",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Strategic",
        "traitid": 3,
        "relationship": [
            78,
            86,
            17,
            64,
            22,
            65,
            22,
            15,
            94,
            16,
            90,
            34,
            19,
            90,
            74,
            33,
            53,
            46,
            12,
            93,
            18,
            97,
            72,
            57
        ],
        "power": 100,
        "startingnum": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "Sue",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Strategic",
        "traitid": 3,
        "relationship": [
            72,
            39,
            89,
            48,
            74,
            26,
            93,
            37,
            48,
            17,
            79,
            39,
            82,
            56,
            15,
            14,
            10,
            52,
            67,
            100,
            19,
            21,
            76,
            29
        ],
        "power": 88.599348534202,
        "startingnum": 12
    },
    {
        "name": "Adam",
        "gender": "Male",
        "trait": "Logistical",
        "traitid": 0,
        "relationship": [
            60,
            71,
            33,
            72,
            31,
            90,
            20,
            71,
            28,
            93,
            45,
            57,
            98,
            46,
            85,
            92,
            33,
            18,
            19,
            66,
            77,
            31,
            14,
            26
        ],
        "power": 80.94462540716614,
        "startingnum": 1
    },
    {
        "name": "Lela",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Diplomatic",
        "traitid": 2,
        "relationship": [
            75,
            61,
            54,
            74,
            81,
            47,
            55,
            83,
            30,
            39,
            73,
            21,
            58,
            67,
            93,
            79,
            46,
            12,
            100,
            72,
            66,
            18,
            73,
            47
        ],
        "power": 80.13029315960914,
        "startingnum": 8
    },
    {
        "name": "Fanny",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Diplomatic",
        "traitid": 2,
        "relationship": [
            38,
            61,
            61,
            29,
            45,
            77,
            17,
            56,
            88,
            44,
            48,
            65,
            82,
            49,
            64,
            79,
            95,
            61,
            98,
            41,
            53,
            73,
            87,
            39
        ],
        "power": 76.38436482084691,
        "startingnum": 18
    },
    {
        "name": "Bernice",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Diplomatic",
        "traitid": 2,
        "relationship": [
            99,
            82,
            60,
            35,
            59,
            22,
            80,
            41,
            26,
            64,
            76,
            75,
            47,
            86,
            19,
            12,
            38,
            81,
            88,
            78,
            23,
            34,
            12,
            38
        ],
        "power": 67.75244299674269,
        "startingnum": 5
    },
    {
        "name": "Charlotte",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Logistical",
        "traitid": 0,
        "relationship": [
            99,
            30,
            90,
            34,
            24,
            71,
            15,
            86,
            61,
            40,
            79,
            55,
            86,
            19,
            90,
            41,
            91,
            98,
            22,
            13,
            14,
            92,
            91,
            39
        ],
        "power": 64.33224755700327,
        "startingnum": 19
    },
    {
        "name": "Myrtie",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Tactical",
        "traitid": 1,
        "relationship": [
            24,
            32,
            26,
            93,
            46,
            93,
            70,
            78,
            92,
            69,
            46,
            18,
            83,
            42,
            67,
            46,
            86,
            73,
            83,
            20,
            43,
            66,
            66,
            54
        ],
        "power": 61.56351791530946,
        "startingnum": 0
    },
    {
        "name": "Lily",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Logistical",
        "traitid": 0,
        "relationship": [
            57,
            66,
            95,
            67,
            36,
            61,
            95,
            85,
            38,
            72,
            84,
            97,
            45,
            12,
            88,
            16,
            32,
            26,
            84,
            72,
            50,
            13,
            97,
            39
        ],
        "power": 61.07491856677526,
        "startingnum": 21
    },
    {
        "name": "Willie",
        "gender": "Male",
        "trait": "Strategic",
        "traitid": 3,
        "relationship": [
            50,
            89,
            26,
            24,
            76,
            95,
            71,
            62,
            79,
            33,
            37,
            33,
            93,
            10,
            16,
            24,
            26,
            38,
            41,
            60,
            40,
            70,
            85,
            46
        ],
        "power": 51.79153094462542,
        "startingnum": 13
    },
    {
        "name": "Madge",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Strategic",
        "traitid": 3,
        "relationship": [
            14,
            57,
            35,
            68,
            65,
            27,
            72,
            24,
            86,
            94,
            64,
            39,
            73,
            94,
            26,
            41,
            10,
            88,
            23,
            85,
            56,
            88,
            45,
            46
        ],
        "power": 51.62866449511403,
        "startingnum": 3
    },
    {
        "name": "Dollie",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Strategic",
        "traitid": 3,
        "relationship": [
            30,
            81,
            57,
            22,
            82,
            54,
            60,
            14,
            56,
            45,
            79,
            33,
            46,
            89,
            52,
            56,
            89,
            78,
            36,
            63,
            31,
            31,
            15,
            36
        ],
        "power": 49.67426710097722,
        "startingnum": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Dennis",
        "gender": "Male",
        "trait": "Tactical",
        "traitid": 1,
        "relationship": [
            68,
            17,
            39,
            34,
            87,
            17,
            20,
            81,
            74,
            62,
            99,
            88,
            25,
            92,
            33,
            51,
            17,
            87,
            66,
            100,
            99,
            89,
            12,
            58
        ],
        "power": 44.46254071661239,
        "startingnum": 7
    },
    {
        "name": "Inez",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Tactical",
        "traitid": 1,
        "relationship": [
            80,
            79,
            56,
            73,
            25,
            51,
            29,
            71,
            74,
            95,
            69,
            12,
            54,
            79,
            72,
            100,
            72,
            19,
            66,
            15,
            95,
            41,
            14,
            39
        ],
        "power": 41.04234527687297,
        "startingnum": 22
    },
    {
        "name": "Harry",
        "gender": "Male",
        "trait": "Logistical",
        "traitid": 0,
        "relationship": [
            72,
            52,
            69,
            94,
            10,
            24,
            77,
            65,
            56,
            51,
            17,
            20,
            31,
            39,
            24,
            28,
            85,
            51,
            34,
            34,
            64,
            70,
            67,
            29
        ],
        "power": 39.90228013029318,
        "startingnum": 16
    },
    {
        "name": "Ronald",
        "gender": "Male",
        "trait": "Logistical",
        "traitid": 0,
        "relationship": [
            63,
            99,
            63,
            68,
            45,
            58,
            71,
            24,
            13,
            20,
            77,
            83,
            35,
            36,
            51,
            74,
            100,
            46,
            70,
            74,
            42,
            55,
            38,
            41
        ],
        "power": 37.133550488599354,
        "startingnum": 9
    },
    {
        "name": "Isabella",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Strategic",
        "traitid": 3,
        "relationship": [
            55,
            76,
            72,
            83,
            31,
            48,
            94,
            65,
            61,
            39,
            31,
            63,
            94,
            82,
            38,
            50,
            37,
            15,
            24,
            54,
            24,
            32,
            92,
            49
        ],
        "power": 35.99348534201956,
        "startingnum": 14
    },
    {
        "name": "Steve",
        "gender": "Male",
        "trait": "Diplomatic",
        "traitid": 2,
        "relationship": [
            85,
            79,
            47,
            29,
            28,
            13,
            14,
            48,
            75,
            55,
            71,
            20,
            76,
            53,
            13,
            88,
            91,
            26,
            79,
            47,
            50,
            75,
            70,
            29
        ],
        "power": 32.736156351791536,
        "startingnum": 15
    },
    {
        "name": "Clara",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Diplomatic",
        "traitid": 2,
        "relationship": [
            26,
            59,
            92,
            76,
            27,
            93,
            15,
            40,
            97,
            69,
            78,
            23,
            77,
            21,
            18,
            13,
            12,
            34,
            57,
            100,
            32,
            21,
            13,
            54
        ],
        "power": 31.433224755700323,
        "startingnum": 20
    },
    {
        "name": "Wesley",
        "gender": "Male",
        "trait": "Logistical",
        "traitid": 0,
        "relationship": [
            29,
            88,
            19,
            50,
            13,
            89,
            24,
            11,
            63,
            19,
            28,
            82,
            71,
            59,
            26,
            63,
            49,
            66,
            94,
            36,
            86,
            18,
            47,
            36
        ],
        "power": 27.035830618892504,
        "startingnum": 11
    },
    {
        "name": "Douglas",
        "gender": "Male",
        "trait": "Diplomatic",
        "traitid": 2,
        "relationship": [
            19,
            41,
            20,
            67,
            14,
            93,
            31,
            63,
            60,
            54,
            85,
            68,
            89,
            50,
            65,
            69,
            77,
            23,
            86,
            10,
            38,
            87,
            16,
            40
        ],
        "power": 25.89576547231271,
        "startingnum": 17
    },
    {
        "name": "Fannie",
        "gender": "Female",
        "trait": "Tactical",
        "traitid": 1,
        "relationship": [
            77,
            19,
            80,
            13,
            21,
            42,
            44,
            96,
            66,
            40,
            72,
            47,
            45,
            69,
            53,
            52,
            60,
            64,
            33,
            95,
            88,
            79,
            52,
            42
        ],
        "power": 24.429967426710103,
        "startingnum": 6
    },
    {
        "name": "Isaac",
        "gender": "Male",
        "trait": "Tactical",
        "traitid": 1,
        "relationship": [
            37,
            75,
            63,
            53,
            89,
            73,
            17,
            31,
            34,
            42,
            96,
            72,
            70,
            28,
            49,
            50,
            25,
            22,
            100,
            46,
            18,
            87,
            67,
            52
        ],
        "power": 11.400651465798038,
        "startingnum": 4
    },
    {
        "name": "You",
        "gender": "squid",
        "trait": "none",
        "traitid": -1,
        "power": 0,
        "startingnum": 24,
        "relationship": [
            73,
            60,
            44,
            49,
            41,
            89,
            46,
            28,
            95,
            58,
            93,
            24,
            67,
            52,
            92,
            32,
            13,
            37,
            89,
            23,
            69,
            89,
            33,
            37
        ]
    }
]"
```

Etc. I'm trying to sort this array by the power level of each user(object). I'm using the code below to sort it:

```
function SortByPower(obj1, obj2) {
    // Ascending: first power more than the previous
    return obj2.power - obj1.power;
};
users.sort(SortByPower);//sort the users by power
```

However, it seems to either only be shifting the positions of the power values, or everything else. You can see what's going on and view it in action at [labs.questionable.co.nz/projects/raise](http://labs.questionable.co.nz/projects/raise/). Things you can use in the log:

- updateplc() (sorts the users in the array, then sends it to the table)
- users (shows the variable which contains all 24 users)

Comment: The script file in question is here: [http://labs.questionable.co.nz/projects/raise/js/scripts.js](http://labs.questionable.co.nz/projects/raise/js/scripts.js)

Comment: That doesn't look like valid array nor object in javascript, show us what you've really got ?

Comment: @adeneo if you visit the page and enter "users" into the console, you can see the full array. I was just cutting out parts so that i didn't hit the character limit

Comment: We generally don't visit random pages and type stuff, you post what's relevant here. To get a valid object that is easier to copy/paste, type `JSON.stringify(users, null, 4)` in your console

Comment: @adeneo Okay, fixed. Sorry, this is the first time I've asked a question on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use lodash it will would be something like this (taken from lodash documentation)

```
_.sortBy([1, 2, 3], function(num) { return Math.sin(num); });
// → [3, 1, 2]

_.sortBy([1, 2, 3], function(num) { return this.sin(num); }, Math);
// → [3, 1, 2]

var characters = [
  { 'name': 'barney',  'age': 36 },
  { 'name': 'fred',    'age': 40 },
  { 'name': 'barney',  'age': 26 },
  { 'name': 'fred',    'age': 30 }
];

// using "_.pluck" callback shorthand
_.map(_.sortBy(characters, 'age'), _.values);
// → [['barney', 26], ['fred', 30], ['barney', 36], ['fred', 40]]

// sorting by multiple properties
_.map(_.sortBy(characters, ['name', 'age']), _.values);
// = > [['barney', 26], ['barney', 36], ['fred', 30], ['fred', 40]]
```

An excellent example of what you are trying to do is the accepted answer on here: [Sorting JavaScript Object by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value)

Comment: In the end it turned out to be another problem in the script that was causing this to not work, but marking as accepted anyway because it answered the question.